# Why is wp_localize_script returning false?

Tags: ajax, javascript, wp-localize-script

I am enqueuing the script.js via a plugin succesfully but the wp_localize_script is not working and returning false. I have no clue why...

object_name is unavailable in the script.js when I remove the var_dump

```
function my_enqueue() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/script.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
  var_dump(wp_localize_script( 'ajax_script', 'object_name', array( 'foo' => 'bar' ) ));
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Handle name doesn't match registered script name in your snippet.

`wp_enqueue_script` has `ajax-script` and localize has `ajax_script` notice the dash and underscore.

You should also follow example from the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) a. register, b. localise, c. enqueue; like so:

```
<?php

// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

Comment: aah it had to be some weird typo, thank you! just enqueuing and the then localizing it seems to work fine for me though

Comment: @koedev yes that's fine, docs in the notes says: `IMPORTANT! wp_localize_script() MUST be called after the script has been registered using wp_register_script() or wp_enqueue_script().` So your good.